# Perl numerical sorting: how to ignore leading alpha character

Tags: perl, sorting, arrays

I have a 1,660 row array like this:

```
...
H00504
H00085
H00181
H00500
H00103
H00007
H00890
H08793
H94316
H00217
...
```

And the leading character never changes. It is always "H" then five digits. But when I do what I believe is a numerical sort in Perl, I'm getting strange results. Some segments are sorted in order, but then a different segment starts up. Here is a segment after sorting:

```
...
H01578
H01579
H01580
H01581
H01582
H01583
H01584
H00536
H00537
H00538
H01585
H01586
H01587
H01588
H01589
H01590
...
```

What I'm trying is this:

```
my @sorted_array = sort {$a <=> $b} @raw_array;
```

But obviously it is not working. Anyone know why?

I should add that, although these values all have "H" prepended, there remains the possibility that in the future we might end up with additional data prepended with some other letter. This means that removing the H, sorting, then replacing the H, is not a solution

Comment: I should add that, although these values all have "H" prepended, there remains the possibility that in the future we might end up with additional data prepended with some other letter. This means that removing the H, sorting, then replacing the H, is not a solution.

Comment: ...because it is impossible to replace the letter H?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you were using `use strict; use warnings;` as you should, you would have gotten numerous errors of the form

```
Argument "H01578" isn't numeric in numeric comparison (<=>)
```

None of your elements are numbers, so they're all considered zero. That's why Perl considers the result of your current code sorted.

---

If you want to sort by letter then by number (which is the same as sorting just by number since all the letters are the same):

```
my @sorted_array = sort @raw_array;
```

which is short for

```
my @sorted_array = sort { $a cmp $b } @raw_array;
```

If you wanted to sort by number regardless of the leading letter, you'd use the following instead:

```
my @sorted_array =
   sort { substr($a, 1) <=> substr($b, 1) }
    @raw_array;
```

Comment: +1  Recommend sticking with the `sort @ary`, however, since the OP clarified (in a comment to self) that the 'H' prefix may someday be other letters.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to realize that this is best handled by the default sort.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to sort by your initial character as primary key followed by the digits as secondary key then you can use a variation of the [*Schwartzian Transform*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=9108) which extracts the two fields for comparison from all the data before sorting.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = <DATA>;
chomp @data;

my @sorted = sort map $_->[0],
sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] or $a->[2] <=> $b->[2] }
map [$_, /(.)(.+)/], @data;

print "$_\n" for @sorted;

__DATA__
A1180
B0802
B1284
C0899
C1455
C0765
A1207
A0909
C0921
C1060
A1067
B1486
A1268
B0772
C0595
B0734
A1004
A0607
A1323
B1181
```

**output**

```
A0607
A0909
A1004
A1067
A1180
A1207
A1268
A1323
B0734
B0772
B0802
B1181
B1284
B1486
C0595
C0765
C0899
C0921
C1060
C1455
```

Tool completed successfully

You may prefer an alternative, which doesn't use the Transform. This program has identical output but will run significantly more slowly for large datasets

```
my @sorted = sort {
  my @a = $a =~ /(.)(.+)/;
  my @b = $b =~ /(.)(.+)/;
  $a[0] cmp $b[0] or $a[1] <=> $b[1];
} @data;
```

Comment: How is that different than `my @sorted = sort @data;` for fixed width numbers?

Answer (score 4):

To ignore to anything what is not a number, you can also:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted =    sort {
                        (my $x = $a) =~ s/\D//g;
                        (my $y = $b) =~ s/\D//g;
                        ($x?$x:0) <=> ($y?$y:0)
                } <DATA>;
print "$_" for @sorted;

__DATA__
a123
a/9999/gyu
b2
333
bbb
c888hh
0
```

result:

```
bbb
0
b2
a123
333
c888hh
a/9999/gyu
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like:

```
my @sorted_array = sort {substr($a, 1) <=> substr($b,1)} @raw_array;
```

See: http://ideone.com/trnfy for an example.

If you used the standard sort, without the `{...}`, that should work as well.  Your current code is probably failing because all of the comparisons return 0, because you are doing a numeric comparison on alphanumeric data.

Comment: see also `List::UtilsBy::sort_by`

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the Schwartzian transforms and other related noise by using `List::UtilsBy::sort_by`:

```
use List::UtilsBy qw( sort_by );

my @sorted_array = sort_by { substr($_, 1) } @raw_array;
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Yup, much. Thanks! Your post was listed in the low quality queue before.